# Pi hangs when booting

Tags: boot, dhcp

I have a clean new Raspbian Jessie installed via NOOBS today. No special things done.

When I start it from the SD card it hangs right after the funny colored image with the following screen:

```
udhcp (v1.23.1) started
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
No lease, failing
Starting system message bus: done
```

It won't continue booting until I hit ESC on keyboard. Then it continues booting with its well known long boot logs with the green [OK]'s scrolling up and ending on the GUI.

```
$pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
$pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19+ #858 Tue Mar 15 15:52:03 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Any idea?

---

Further details:

- [/var/log/syslog](https://paste.debian.net/422117/) (pressed ESC key at 09:13:20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Raspberrian a third time since I messed up its config. Anyhow it now works flawlessly. Don't understand what the problem was the second times before. Maybe my SD card is broken?

Answer (score 3):

For whatever reason your Pi is not getting an IP address assigned by DHCP. This is almost certainly due to some factor external to the Pi (unless you have seriously modified the Pi settings).

You can get the Pi to boot by the appropriate setting in `raspi-config`. I can't remember the exact name, but it is something like don't wait for network.

The default `systemd` settings cause the Pi to wait for a network as there are a number of other services (e.g. `ntp`) dependent on networking.

This will cause it to boot, and the services will run when (and if) a network becomes available.

Comment: The Pi can get its network IP via DHCP after I pressed the ESC key without any problem. The network is connected all the time to the router my pc is also connected to. In the raspi-config the Pi is already set to "Fast Boot without waiting for network connection". Any hint on the mentioned systemd settings - Is it the same option as in raspi-config or a completely other thing?

Answer (score 1):

its possible that he delay the startup because your dhcp client is unable to get an ip from your router.

do you connected a network cable into a router or how you done it?

if the settings regarding network are still default your linux will try to get the ip by a dhcp server for your network device. if this fails he will delay the startup because he probably try it several times before he give up.

if you dont have one try to setup a static ip for your network device in /etc/network/interfaces

or if you dont need network try to disable it to get the os booting faster.

Comment: I connect via cable to several dhcp routers and via single cable to another computer. The ip must be set via dhcp in my usecase (very often changing network and location). Network/Internet access is important! So I cant switch to static ip. The dhcp client just works fine after pressing ESC. Then it connects without problems but hangs until key is pressed. Its a big problem since I dont have the possibility to carry a big keyboard nor do I have a screen to figure out if and where it hangs.

Comment: you should check your var/log/boot.log and var/log/dmsg logfiles. maybe this will show the exact problem. feel free to post them here. this could lead into a solution.

Comment: Thx for your help. `/var/log/boot.log` does not exist and `/var/log/dmsg` is empty with message "(Nothing has been logged yet.)".

Comment: Added `/var/log/syslog` to main question.